# How to get the element that holds the currently running script?

Tags: javascript

I have a large DOM structure built by a script. Currently I'm using a dummy object with an id to mark where I want the structure to be but it occurred to me that the script element itself could possibly serve the same function.. anyways, it would be neat.

example:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script src="mydoodad.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

So what I want is to get the reference to that specific script tag inside mydoodad.js without giving it an id or a class or querying the src attribute value.

The result would be a neat way to include widgets and whatnot in a more in-line fashion, just drop a script element where ever and the widget would appear in its place.

Comment: Smelling bad design ...? Anyway, if the scripts are executed immediately after parsing, the script on the execution is `document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1)`. There's also [`currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript).

Comment: So if I understand right, you want to create a component and want to place a script tag and replace it with some element. Am I right?

Comment: @teemu whats so bad about it? I tried your suggestions, currentScript works good but I'm not thrilled about its browser compatibility. document.scripts seems to contain all the script elements in the document, even ones that It shouldn't have gotten to yet so using the current length to find the currently executing one doesn't work for me.. at least on the latest chrome.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to say whether `scripts` collection can be used or not. It contains _loaded_ scripts in the order of load, hence the last member refers to the one which is currently executed, when executing an inline script. Not working with event handlers or any async action, including async script loading, though. [About the design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).